# Adicionar novo campo ao banco com Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails4

Inseri uma nova coluna na minha tabela `contents` e também inclui o campo no formulario com o mesmo nome da coluna na tabela de criação `(client_id)`, porém esse dado não é inserido quando crio um novo registro.

Já adicionei o `symbol` no controller;

```
params.require(:content).permit(:title, :content, :client_alteration, :target, :scheduled_to, :status, :comment, :client_id)
```

O HTML

```
<div class="field">
<%= f.label 'Cliente' %>
<%= select_tag 'client_id', options_from_collection_for_select(@clients, 'id', 'name') %>
```

Comment: Rafael, você quis dizer que o Rails não auto-incrementa o seu id automáticamente ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Rafael,  o problema é que você não está passando `client_id` como um atributo contents (usando o `f` ) em seu formulário, nos casos como o seu, eu particularmente gosto de usar o [collection_select](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html#method-i-collection_select), ficaria mais ou menos assim:

```
<div class="field">
  <%= f.label 'Cliente' %>
  <%= f.collection_select :client_id, @clients, :id, :name %>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

O `select_tag` cria um campo específico dentro dos `params` e não dentro do `content`. 
Você precisa do campo `client_id` dentro de `content (params[:content][:client_id])`, mas o campo que esta sendo passado é provavelmente `params[:client_id]`.

Comment: eu gerei o controller com o `scaffold` e achei que ele já incluiria isso dentro do `param`, onde eu precisaria mudar entao?}

Comment: Não sei se é uma boa idéia usar atribuicao de massa com campos de chave estrangeira. Normalmente nesses casos eu instancio a entidade e associo ela ao objeto que está sendo salvo. Por exemplo:

`client = Client.find(params[:client_id]`


`@content.client = client`